# After resetting iPhone, photos are not accesible via cable connection

Tags: iphone, photos, storage

I have a 16 GB iPhone 6 and as most of you might have experienced, after a certain point in its lifetime, that amount of space gets filled in a couple of weeks or months. Previously what I used to do was connect it to my PC and move my photos to my hard drive and free the space.

Gradually the phone started getting filled with junk and I didn't even have space for photos. The only solution I found was to reset my phone. I did that and everything was fine, but now my photos are starting to fill my phone again. But for some reason after the reset I can't actually see my photo folders. I see the iPhone on My Computer, I can open its internal storage which shows actual usage, but inside it I don't have access to the folders.

I tried resetting privacy settings, but it didn't change anything. I also give permission to access each time I connect the phone for some reason.

Other than that this is what I see when I open the phone's storage:

[image: Storage appears]

[image: No folders]

Comment: Perhaps:... https://macroplant.com/iexplorer?gclid=Cj0KCQiAh9njBRCYARIsALJhQkHbyFdgHGPcZVSX-RG1ZyRbjybEe4xRZZMiTFPLwUJycSekmYQAerQaAh_rEALw_wcB

Comment: @historystamp didn't work. Shows only single images where it should show a bunch. I did trust the computer acces through the phone, so I don't think that was a permission error.